# Looking for sound drivers for Dell Optiplex 755

Tags: drivers, sound, dell, pulseaudio

I'm running on 16.04, not a lot of experience working with Ubuntu and will need very detailed explanations.

I did a basic iso install i found off the Ubuntu site and i have yet to get my sound driver working. I can't find any sound card in the system info. Dell said it came with a sound card on the MoBo. <~ might be toast. idk.

Thanks for your help.